# python pandas change dataframe to pivoted columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe that looks as following:

```
Type Month  Value
A    1      0.29
A    2      0.90
A    3      0.44
A    4      0.43
B    1      0.29
B    2      0.50
B    3      0.14
B    4      0.07
```

I want to change the dataframe to following format:

```
Type    A      B
1      0.29    0.29
2      0.90    0.50
3      0.44    0.14
4      0.43    0.07
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas long to wide reshape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_index` + `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Month', 'Type']).Value.unstack()

Type      A     B
Month            
1      0.29  0.29
2      0.90  0.50
3      0.44  0.14
4      0.43  0.07
```

To match your exact output

```
df.set_index(['Month', 'Type']).Value.unstack().rename_axis(None)

Type      A     B
1      0.29  0.29
2      0.90  0.50
3      0.44  0.14
4      0.43  0.07
```

Comment: df.set_index(['Month','Type']).squeeze().unstack().rename_axis(None) if you are to lazy to remember the name of that pesky "Value" column. A trick @TedPetrou showed me.

Comment: @ScottBoston I'm not perfect, but I try to provide solutions that are generalizable, or is obvious how to generalize (I'm certain you can find posts of mine where this isn't `True`).  IMO `squeeze` obscures what is happening **and** if by chance the dataframe had another column, it would not work as intended.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Pivot solution:

```
In [70]: df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Type', values='Value')
Out[70]:
Type      A     B
Month
1      0.29  0.29
2      0.90  0.50
3      0.44  0.14
4      0.43  0.07

In [71]: df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Type', values='Value').rename_axis(None)
Out[71]:
Type     A     B
1     0.29  0.29
2     0.90  0.50
3     0.44  0.14
4     0.43  0.07
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having a case of long format table which you want to transform to a wide format.

This is natively handled in `pandas`:

```
df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Type', values='Value')
```