# Combining similar dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this

```
User    Date     FeatureA FeatureB
John    DateA      1        2
John    DateB      3        5
```

Is there anyway that I can combine the 2 rows such that it becomes

```
  User    Date1    Date2    FeatureA1 FeatureB1 FeatureA2 FeatureB2
  John    DateA    DateB        1        2          3        5
```

Comment: Do you want to combine all rows that have the same `User`? Can you have more than two rows that have the same `User`?

Comment: @DyZ I would like to combine all rows that have the same User such that the dataframe would only have unique Users

Comment: Do you have an answer to the second part of my question?

Comment: @DyZ For the 2nd part of your question, I do not wish to have more than one row that have the same User

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Can the original data have _more than two_ rows that have the same `User`?

Comment: Yes, the original data can have more than 2 rows of the same user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas long to wide reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
g = df.groupby(['User']).cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['User', g]).unstack()
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(i, j+1) for i, j in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   User  Date1  Date2  FeatureA1  FeatureA2  FeatureB1  FeatureB2
0  John  DateA  DateB          1          3          2          5
```

Explanation:

1. Get count per groups by `User`s with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
2. Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
4. Flatenning `MultiIndex` in columns
5. Convert `index` to columns by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)