# Convert csv file with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new into python, does somebody have an idea what would be a good approach? I could just script it, but it's probably faster to use a package.

I have this .csv file (gigabytes large):

```
name,   value,  time
A,   1, 10
B,   2, 10
C,   3, 10
C,   3, 10 (should ignore duplicates, or non complete (A,B,C) entries
A,   4, 12 (should be sorted by time, this entry should be at the end, after time==11)
B,   5, 12
C,   6, 12
B,   7, 11 (order of A,B,C might be different)
C,   8, 11
A,   9, 11
```

convert it to a new .csv file containing:

```
time,   A,  B,  C
10, 1,  2,  3
11, 9,  7,  8
12, 4,  5,  6
```

Comment: What OS are you working on?

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: A good approach would be to research how you can parse CSV with python, and figure out an algorithm that will do what you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: Aside from filtering, the operation you're trying to do is [converting long-form data to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates().pivot('time','name','value')
print (df)
name  A  B  C
time         
10    1  2  3
11    9  7  8
12    4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful! I was stuck at just reading the csv file. Together with the addition of @divyang this solved my question.

Comment: Very useful command this pivot(), the documentation has a very similar example
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: @Sheldon Glad can help!

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment I would like to add to @jezrael answer that you would also want to drop incomplete or NaN values. By using [df.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A = 'a'
B = 'b'
C = 'c'
df = pd.DataFrame([[A,   1, 10],
                [B,   2, 10],
                [C,   3, 10],
                [C,   3, 10],
                [A,   4, 12],
                [B,   5, 12],
                [C,   6, 12],
                [B,   7, 11],
                [C,   8, 11],
                [A,   9, 11],
                [np.nan, 10, 0]], columns = ["name","value", "time"])
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df = df.pivot('time','name','value')
print(df)
```