# Transposing column values into rows and grouping them based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Value     group_id
23        1
28        1
32        1 
....
35        12
23        12
42        12
```

There are 6 unique group_id in total, each with few hundred elements. 
I want to convert this into a dataframe that has the *value* for a single '*group_id*' in one single row. So I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
value_1 value_2 value_3 group_id
23       28      32      1
....
35       23      42      12
```

I tried using pandas.melt and pandas.groupby but failed to get any results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas long to wide reshape, by two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape-by-two-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the the position of the `'Value'` within each group.  We can create it with `groupby.cumcount`

```
df.set_index(
    ['group_id', df.groupby('group_id').cumcount() + 1]
).Value.unstack().add_prefix('Value_').reset_index()

   group_id  Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
0         1       23       28       32
1        12       35       23       42
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` with `cumcount` to fill in your `'value_'` records, and then use `.pivot_table` on the result:

```
df['val_grp'] = 'value_' + (df.groupby('group_id').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

pvt = df.pivot_table(index='group_id', columns='val_grp', values='Value')

print(pvt)
```

Prints:

```
val_grp   value_1  value_2  value_3
group_id                           
1              23       28       32
12             35       23       42
```

---

As mentioned in the comments by andrew_reece, this can be done in a single line by doing:

```
pvt = df.assign(idx=(df.groupby("group_id").cumcount()+1).astype(str).str.replace("^(.)", "value_\\1", regex=True)).pivot(index="group_id", columns="idx", values="Value")
```

However, it should be noted that this requires Pandas 23.0 or higher, as this is when the `regex` parameter for `str.replace` was introduced.

Comment: You can use `assign` to get it all on one chain: `df.assign(idx=df.groupby("group_id").cumcount().astype(str).str.replace("^(.)", "value_\\1", regex=True)).pivot(index="group_id", columns="idx", values="Value")`

Comment: I like this answer and I agree with @andrew_reece.

Comment: @andrew_reece a monster one-liner! I've edited it into my answer (adding one to `.cumcount` to be consistent with OP's column names), thankyou very much!

Comment: For some reason, this did not work with my dataset as the output using this was not in proper order and all messed up. However @piRSquared solution worked flawlessly