# How to stack values if I have repeating columns in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to stack the repeating column values under single column.
For example, if a,b and c are repeating columns with respective values

```
product,a, b, c, a, b, c 

X, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 1
```

Expected result should look like

```
product, a, b, c

X, 1, 3, 2

X, 2, 5, 1
```

Please be informed that before these columns I have "Products" and I need to keep as it repeating for as many new rows added.

I have tried melt in python 3 but it doesn't solve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas long to wide reshape, by two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape-by-two-variables)

Comment: No duplicates in the data

Comment: is product the name of your  table? do you have a unique identifier there such as a day ? do you have anything to tell me how X first row differs from X second row?

Comment: Product is a column in the dataframe, If you see the example given, X is a product with a,b,c values as 1,3,2 and 2,5,1, which are aligned in a single row, but I am expecting the output to be as shown above. Your help would be appreicated @Herc01