# Pandas project a value of a group to every of each member of the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`

```
In [83]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'x': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    ...:     'y': ['event', 'checkpoint', 'name'] * 2,
    ...:     'z': ['half_marathon', 21, 'healthy_run', 'full_marathon', 42, 'worthy_run']
    ...:     })

In [84]: df
Out[84]: 
   x           y              z
0  1       event  half_marathon
1  1  checkpoint             21
2  1        name    healthy_run
3  2       event  full_marathon
4  2  checkpoint             42
5  2        name     worthy_run
```

I would like to have each of `y` variable to become another column and the value in the `z` to be projected in each of the group. The desired `df` would look like this:

```
In [85]: desired_df
Out[85]: 
   x           y              z          event  checkpoint         name
0  1       event  half_marathon  half_marathon          21  healthy_run
1  1  checkpoint             21  half_marathon          21  healthy_run
2  1        name    healthy_run  half_marathon          21  healthy_run
3  2       event  full_marathon  full_marathon          42   worthy_run
4  2  checkpoint             42  full_marathon          42   worthy_run
5  2        name     worthy_run  full_marathon          42   worthy_run
```

I tried with `GroupBy` but I'm not sure how I should project the following example's `checkpoint` to fill each of its group's attribute. What is the best way to project the following `checkpoint` values to each of the member of the group? Thanks!

```
In [87]: _df = df.groupby(['y'])['z'].get_group('checkpoint')

In [88]: df.join(_df, rsuffix='joined_z')
Out[88]: 
   x           y              z zjoined_z
0  1       event  half_marathon       NaN
1  1  checkpoint             21        21
2  1        name    healthy_run       NaN
3  2       event  full_marathon       NaN
4  2  checkpoint             42        42
5  2        name     worthy_run       NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pivot('x','y','z'), on='x')
print (df)
   x           y              z checkpoint          event         name
0  1       event  half_marathon         21  half_marathon  healthy_run
1  1  checkpoint             21         21  half_marathon  healthy_run
2  1        name    healthy_run         21  half_marathon  healthy_run
3  2       event  full_marathon         42  full_marathon   worthy_run
4  2  checkpoint             42         42  full_marathon   worthy_run
5  2        name     worthy_run         42  full_marathon   worthy_run
```

If need ordering of new columns like in original column `y` add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pivot('x','y','z').reindex(df['y'].unique(), axis=1), on='x')
print (df)
   x           y              z          event checkpoint         name
0  1       event  half_marathon  half_marathon         21  healthy_run
1  1  checkpoint             21  half_marathon         21  healthy_run
2  1        name    healthy_run  half_marathon         21  healthy_run
3  2       event  full_marathon  full_marathon         42   worthy_run
4  2  checkpoint             42  full_marathon         42   worthy_run
5  2        name     worthy_run  full_marathon         42   worthy_run
```

Comment: after a year, this solution still very elegant and useful. I'm wondering if there is any other method that can achieve this result?

Comment: @TotoLele another solution for `df.join(df.pivot('x','y','z'), on='x')` ? Alternative is `df.join(df.set_index(['x','y'])['z'].unstack()), on='x')`