# How to create new Dataframe and new columns derived from existing values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 in this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Date': ['2015-02-24','2015-02-24','2015-02-25','2015-02-26'],
'Class': ['E','M','M','H'], 
'Value':[100,200,200,300]})

Date      Class Value
2015-02-24  E   100
2015-02-24  M   200
2015-02-25  M   200
2015-02-26  H   300
```

How can I do in python to make df to df1 in this format:
Make classes "E, M, H" as new column names, and fill in values.

Expected output:

```
Date         E     M     H
2015-02-24  100   200   NaN
2015-02-25  NaN   200   NaN
2015-02-26  NaN   NaN   300
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799916 does it answer your question?

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Class', values='Value')`

Comment: Or `df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Class', values='Value').reindex(columns=pd.Index(['E', 'M', 'H'])).reset_index()` for same order columns in output.