# Reshaping dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reshape my dataset from this:

| Date | Item | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a1 | b1 |
| 1 | 2 | a2 | b2 |
| 1 | 3 | a3 | b3 |

to this

| Date | Letter | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | a1 | a2 | a3 |
| 1 | B | b1 | b2 | b3 |

I have tried using pd.pivot and pd.melt however I am unable to get the correct dataset.

Comment: Does this here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape-by-two-variables

Comment: unfortunately no but thank you

Comment: @kyara, shouldn't the `Letter` column contain `A` and `B` values instead?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you are right, I edited the table thanks

Comment: What else have you tried? There are plenty of other tools you can use, especially lower-level ones like `.stack()` and `.unstack()`. Have you read the docs? [Reshaping and pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html). We also have a canonical question, but it's too broad IMHO: [How can I pivot a dataframe?](/q/47152691/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea I also tried those but probably as I am new to them I have not obtained great results. I have tried a combination of pd.melt() and pd.pivot() getting closer to what I wanted but not exactly the same

Comment: @kyara Well, I seem to have found a solution using them plus a few other things, so I'm not sure what the problem would be. Show us your code. You can [edit] to add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.pivot` result can be [stacked](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with further [`reset_index(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out = (df.pivot(columns='Item', index='Date').stack(0)
       .add_prefix('Item ').reset_index(names=['Date', 'Letter']))
```

---

```
Item  Date Letter Item 1 Item 2 Item 3
0        1      A     a1     a2     a3
1        1      B     b1     b2     b3
```